# Custom labels alignment issue - ASP.Net BarChart

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts, bar-chart

I am creating a chart control with chartype as Bar Chart. When adding custom labels, the labels are not displayed properly (except for the first label). This is happening for both X and Y axis.

[image]

**Code**

```
            chBar.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
            chBar.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
            chBar.Series["Series1"].YValueType = ChartValueType.String;
            chBar.Series["Series1"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
            chBar.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
            chBar.Series["Series1"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";


            int xpos = 0;

            //CustomLabel for Xaxis
            CustomLabel clabelX;
            CustomLabel clabelY;
            foreach(string x in axisXValues.Choices)
            {

                clabelX = new CustomLabel(xpos, xpos + 1, x, xpos, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
                chBar.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(clabelX);
                xpos++;
            }

            chBar.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chBar.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RowIndex in Custom Label constructor should be 0.

```
clabelX = new CustomLabel(xpos, xpos + 1, x, 0, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
```